# Same instance of fitnesse fixture for each script tag

Tags: fitnesse

I am new to `fitnesse` and I am writing a `fitnesse` script and for some requirement, I have the following scenario:

```
|script|fixture1|
|check|do something1|ok|

|script|fixture2|
|check|do something fixtur2|ok|
```

Then something else with same `fixture1`:

```
|script|fixture1|
|check|do something else|ok|
```

In the above scenario, two instances of `fixture1` will be created but I want to avoid that and want to use same object as created in part of first script tag.

Is there any way to re-use the same object?

Comment: added code into code formatting - minor grammar fixes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define both fixture 1 and 2 as libraries, and then use script tables that do not specify a fixture class (ie first row with only script cell)

Or you could (if only fixture 1 instance should be reused) remove the fixture 2 cell from the second table's first row, and add a second row to it containg a cell `push fixture`, a third row `|start|fixture 2|` and a last row `pop fixture`. The third table's first row must finally be changed to just`script`. This will make the third table use the same fixture 1 instance as table 1.